# Where can i get material download free

Tags: materials

Im much confuse with the node editor to get the different material effects. Is there any website where i can download the material for free.

Comment: There probably are some websites out there where you can download different materials, but I suggest that you should go to YouTube and have a look at some tutorials. Personally, I have found BlenderGuru very helpful when it comes to creating materials which are realistic to real world objects.

Comment: check our [Resources for Blender](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15355/11431)